# While installing an NPM socket.io-client occured several problems I cannot solve

Tags: npm, socket.io, npm-install, socket.io-client

I wanted to install npm package socket.io client, so in my directory I run `npm install socket.io-client`, and when it's done I get this message in Terminal :

```
user$ npm install socket.io-client

up to date, audited 1377 packages in 10s

210 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

**6 high severity vulnerabilities**

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

So is it critical or not for the program? I mean if I use command "npm audit fix --force" then after some installations I get **76 vulnerabilities**.

I tried to run npm fix --force but it gives even more vulnerabilities, if I run nmp fix --forse again it shows 6 vulnerabilities like after the first installation.

Comment: When you wrote `nmp fix --forse`, did you mean `npm fix --force`? (Two typos?)

Comment: Yes, sir. I just made a mistake in the post)

Comment: Lovely, please edit the post to fix it. Thanks!